# Is it being faced, faced, or having been faced with the increasing unemployment?

Tags: past-participles, present-participles, participle-clauses

In writing the following sentence, I am hesitating which one (Being faced, faced, having been faced) I should use at the beginning:

> _____ with the increasing unemployment, many people went on strike in most of the European countries.

Syntactically speaking, I think all of them are correct. Are there any nuances among these three?

---

I have corrected a typo "having faced" to "having been faced"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Having faced with unemployment** does not make sense, syntactically or in meaning. You *might* be able to interpret "having faced" as a baroque construction for "having faced off" meaning "having confronted" but that would imply two people facing each other; one cannot face off with unemployment (an abstract noun).

**Being faced with unemployment** is not completely incorrect but is unnatural and overly wordy.

**Faced with unemployment** is correct and concise, and is the proper selection here.

Comment: what about having been faced with, I meant to write this but dropped the "been"